# How to limit a user from deleting a post that isn't theirs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm following this tutorial https://medium.com/@deallen7/how-to-build-a-reddit-like-site-with-ruby-on-rails-7b6cd106463d and got to the part where I add this

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

to my Links Controller. I'm using the devise gem, and when no user is logged in, I'm not supposed to be able to destroy a post through the View but I can.  Is the code above deprecated?

Comment: Devise gives you a user model. For permissions you need another system like [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep reading in the link you posted, the new version, you'll see that it should be

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Further down it show to add this in your view:

```
<% if link.user == current_user %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```

However keep in mind without backend permissions, a skilled user could hack this.  While the example might be a good basic way to get a basic idea of rails, there's a lot of bad practices on how to code here.  I would suggest looking for better materials to learn from.